# how Seperate a string in java without using functions like split & stringtokenizer?

Tags: java

I want to separate a string without using split .can anybody help with my problem I am tried but I cannot find the exact logic. I did separated string with split function and stringtokenizer .

I solved later.. 
`package File;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Java_String_separating {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str = sc.nextLine();

    for(int i = 0; i <str.length();i++) {
        if(str.charAt(i)==' ') {
            System.out.println();
            continue;
        }
        System.out.print(str.charAt(i));
    }
    sc.close();
}
```

}`

Comment: Could you post your approach that you tried (the one without the split and stringtokenizer)?

Comment: Thanks for your reply i solved later.

Comment: i wanted to solved in this way
  for(int i = 0; i <str.length();i++) {
   if(str.charAt(i)==' ') {
    System.out.println();
    continue;
   }
  System.out.print(str.charAt(i));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the length of the sections of string, you could run a for loop and substring it. So you header would look sometjing like:
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i += lenOfSubStrDesired)
You could theb substring by
    str.substring(i, i+lenOfSubStrDesired);

However, if the length of string desired is unknown and you want to split by a delimiter, it gets harder. You could do something with regular expressions, but at that point your just emulating String.split.

Hope this helps, let me know if you need better examples, I am on mobile and my ability to give example code currently is limited.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to separate string in this way..

```
package labFile;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Java_String_separating {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str = sc.nextLine();

        for(int i = 0; i <str.length();i++) {
            if(str.charAt(i)==' ') {
                System.out.println();
                continue;
            }
            System.out.print(str.charAt(i));
        }
        sc.close();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a mixture of `String.indexOf()` and `String.substring()` and iterate over the input while looking for delimiter:

```
String input = "Hello World";
char delimiter = 'o';

var result = new ArrayList<>();
int i, start = 0;
while ((i = input.indexOf(delimiter, start)) > -1) {
  result.add(input.substring(start, i));
  idx = i + 1;
}
if (start != s.length()) {
  result.add(input.substring(start));
}

System.out.println(result); // [Hell,  W, rld]
```